# A rational polytope that is not a 01-polytope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes, lattice-polytopes

A *01-polytope* is the convex hull of some points $S\subseteq\{0,1\}^n$. I wonder, which polytopes can be represented (combinatorially) as 01-polytopes? There are polytopes that cannot have rational coordinates, so those are out. But what about the rest (call them *rational polytopes*)?

> **Question:** is there a rational polytope that is not combinatorially equivalent to a 01-polytope?

I am fine with embedding a polytope into higher dimension to make it 01.

Comment: Doesn’t the number of combinatorial types of (say, simple) polytopes grow too fast for this (I mean, realizing every one as a 01-polytope) to be possible? EDIT: oh, I see, maybe this is what your comment about embedding in higher dimensions was meant to address.

Comment: Embedding in higher dimension does not give you additional 0/1 polytopes. 

If you have a $d$-polytope $P$ embedded in dimension $n$ for some $n>d$ there are always $n-d$ coordinates that you can forget, to obtain a projection of $P$ in $\mathbb R^d$ with the same combinatorial type. If $P$ was 0/1, the projection still is.

Answer (score 6):

Rather obvious in retrospect, but all 01-polytopes are inscribed (the vertices lie on a sphere). So if $P$ is [non-inscribable](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373124/108884), then it can't be a 01-polytope. There are non-inscribable rational polytopes already in dimension three.

Another property of 01-polytopes not shared by all polytopes is that all 2-faces are 3-gons or 4-gons (this is not hard to see but probably proven somwhere in "Lectures on 01-polytopes" by Ziegler). So e.g. the pentagon is not a 01-polytope.

It would be interesting to see an inscribable rational polytope with only 3- and 4-gonal 2-faces that is still not a 01-polytope.

Comment: The 24-cell is an inscribable rational polytope with only 3-gonal 2-faces that is still not a 01-polytope.

Answer (score 4):

Every simplicial polytope is rational, hence there are infinitely many rational polytopes in any fixed dimension. In contrast, there are finitely many 0/1 polytopes, since they cannot have more than $2^n$ vertices.

Comment: In theory the “embedding in higher dimensions” remark could get around this obstruction.

Comment: Embedding in higher dimension does not give you additional 0/1 polytopes. 

If you have a $d$-polytope $P$ embedded in dimension $n$ for some $n>d$ there are always $n-d$ coordinates that you can forget, to obtain a projection of $P$ in $\mathbb R^d$ with the same combinatorial type. If $P$ was 0/1, the projection still is.